# Select legend name to display in dc.js barchart

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I'm working on a dc.js bar-chart, I have the following dimension:

```
const barDimension = ndx.dimension((d) => [d.variable1, d.variable2]);
```

In the chart, I'd like to display only the first variable as a label but at the moment the chart is displaying both variables comma separated.

```
chart
  .dimension(barDimension)
  .group(barGroup)
  .renderTitle(false)
  .width(width)
  .height(350)
  .margins({
    top: 30,
    right: 12,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 40,
  })
  .x(d3.scaleBand())
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .brushOn(false)
  .transitionDuration(0)
  .barPadding(0.4)
  .outerPadding(0.2)
  .ordering((d) => {
    // custom order function
    return -1;
  })
  .colorAccessor((d) => d)
  .colors((d) => this.getColor(d.key, data));
```

This is the chart definition, I tried using chart.legendables function but seems not working.
The chart variable is `dc.BarChart` object.

**EDIT**
What I'd like to change is not the label on top but the label at the bttom of the chart, see screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Alright, let's get the terminology nailed down. The *label* appears above the bar (or on top of pie slices). The *legend* is the guide displayed outside of the chart which shows what different colors mean. A *title* is a tooltip. You are looking to change the *x axis tick format*.

Comment: Ah, sorry I got the point

Comment: `chart.xAxis().tickFormat(...)` [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/v1.0.12/README.md#axis_tickFormat)

Comment: And yeah... the terminology is totally arbitrary, and may be different from other charting libraries. But it definitely helps when searching for answers. We should probably have a diagram showing anatomy of a chart somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [label accessor](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#label__anchor) on the dc.js chart.

You need to check the type of d in every case and write your accessor accordingly.

I cannot see the data used by your chart so cannot answer it perfectly. But below code might help you:

```
.label(function(d) { return d.key.split(',')[0]; })
```

```js
chart
  .dimension(barDimension)
  .group(barGroup)
  .renderTitle(false)
  .width(width)
  .height(350)
  .margins({
    top: 30,
    right: 12,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 40,
  })
  .x(d3.scaleBand())
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .brushOn(false)
  .transitionDuration(0)
  .barPadding(0.4)
  .outerPadding(0.2)
  .ordering((d) => {
    // custom order function
    return -1;
  })
  .colorAccessor((d) => d)
  .colors((d) => this.getColor(d.key, data));
  .label(function(d) { return d.key.split(',')[0]; })
```

**Solution to resolve the rotation of bar chart labels**

You can simply use the CSS to rotate the x axis labels.

```
#chartContainterId .x.axis text {
    text-anchor: end !important;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: It may also be `d.key[0]` if the key has not been converted to a string before inserting in crossfilter.

Comment: True, I have not checked but we can resolve it using label. I am sure that this d3 problem will be definitely solved now as Gordon is here.

Comment: @Gordon I've made a change on the question, I'm looking for changing the label at the bottom the bar not on top of it

Comment: @Tinwor I have updated my answer to rotate your x axis labels.

Answer (score 1):

The general question was "what are all the labels on a chart and how do I change them?"

So here is the general answer, in case it helps anyone else.

I also put this information [on the wiki](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/Parts-of-a-chart).

[image: labels on dc.js bar chart]

- [xAxisLabel](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#xAxisLabel__anchor)
- [yAxisLabel](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#yAxisLabel__anchor)
- [label](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#label__anchor)
- [title](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#title__anchor)

To change axis labels, first get the axis object using [.xAxis()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#xAxis__anchor) or [.yAxis()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CordinateGridMixin.html#yAxis__anchor). Then use [`.tickFormat()` or other d3-axis methods](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#axes-d3-axis) to change the text. Be sure to [do this in a separate statement](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis) or confusion may occur.